# InfoPath 2007 - adding an attribute and childNodes through Managed Code

Tags: infopath-2007

I’m converting my InfoPath 2003 Object Model Codes to InfoPath 2007 Managed Code, I want to add an attribute and childNodes to a section of form on form load event (FormEvents_Loading).  I want to update the following section:

I was to add an attribute to **mstns:SpecificBook** node and a few child node. The result should be:

**My InfoPath 2003 Object Model code**

To Adding and Set attribute values:

flag = TheXDocument.DOM.createAttribute("active")
prereqsNode.attributes.setNamedItem(flagNode).text = "true"

newNode = doc.CreateNode(NodeTypeElemt, FromNamespacePrefix, "Book",FormNamespace)

```
        specificBookAttrib = newNode.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute("BookId")
        specificBookIdAttrib.Value = “anybook”
        newNode.Attributes.Append(specificBookIdAttrib)
```

SpecificBookNode.AppendChild(newNode)

Can anybody help me convert the line above use Manage code?

Answer (score 1):

Since I could create a new attribute because the sampledata.xml had a default value although my Template.xml have none; I could not it set that value because it read only. 
prereqsNode = navigator.SelectSingleNode (“//mstns:SpecificBook”,  Me.NamespaceManager)

*Error “Duplicate attribute”
prereqsNode.CreateAttribute("", "areLoaded", "", "true")

Error “Read only”
prereqsNode.SetValue("true")*

I decided to create a new XmlDocument:

- create a new attribute  replace the
- entire mstns:SpecificBook node

I also used XmlDocument to create the childNodes, convert the node to navigator and then append childNodes.

Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim newNode As XmlNode
Dim activeAttrib As XmlAttribute

activeAttrib = newNode.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute("active")
activeAttrib.Value = True
newNode.Attributes.Append(activeAttrib)

specificBookNode.ReplaceSelf(newNode.OuterXml)